# Node-red-contrib-ros and Rosbridge communication trouble

Tags: node-red

I'm using Node-red embedded into an existing application to communicate with ROS.

I'm using the node-red-contrib-ros package for node-red which provide subscribing/publishing and ros-server nodes in order to communicate with Rosbridge.

I have connected the said nodes to my rosbridge WebSocket (Both outputs saying 'connected', and getting the green square under the node).
It works well with my publishing node, I even created new type of msgs easily,

It seems like I can't receive any information from my subscriber (No output in debug tab/console, meanwhile a 'rostopic echo' shows me that data IS passing through.).

Edit:

Here are some more intels about my configuration:

I'm running with:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,
ROS Indigo,
NodeJS LTS version (8.9.4),
npm v5.6,
Node-Red v0.17.5,
"Node-red-contrib-ros" Package (1.0.8).

To connect ROS to node-red I use RosBridge, here are the logs:

```
* /rosapi/params_glob: []
* /rosapi/services_glob: []
* /rosapi/topics_glob: []
* /rosbridge_websocket/address:
* /rosbridge_websocket/authenticate: False
* /rosbridge_websocket/delay_between_messages: 0
* /rosbridge_websocket/fragment_timeout: 600
* /rosbridge_websocket/max_message_size: None
* /rosbridge_websocket/params_glob: []
* /rosbridge_websocket/port: 9090
* /rosbridge_websocket/retry_startup_delay: 5
* /rosbridge_websocket/services_glob: []
* /rosbridge_websocket/topics_glob: []
* /rosdistro: indigo
* /rosversion: 1.11.16

NODES
/
rosapi (rosapi/rosapi_node)
rosbridge_websocket (rosbridge_server/rosbridge_websocket)

?[1mROS_MASTER_URI=http://control:11311?[0m
?]2;/opt/pal/dubnium/share/rosbridge_server/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch http://control:11311?
core service [/rosout] found
?[1mprocess[rosbridge_websocket-1]: started with pid [8953]?[0m
?[1mprocess[rosapi-2]: started with pid [8967]?[0m
registered capabilities (classes):
- rosbridge_library.capabilities.call_service.CallService
- rosbridge_library.capabilities.advertise.Advertise
- rosbridge_library.capabilities.publish.Publish
- rosbridge_library.capabilities.subscribe.Subscribe
- <class 'rosbridge_library.capabilities.defragmentation.Defragment'>
- rosbridge_library.capabilities.advertise_service.AdvertiseService
- rosbridge_library.capabilities.service_response.ServiceResponse
- rosbridge_library.capabilities.unadvertise_service.UnadvertiseService
the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
[INFO] [WallTime: 1515408679.756172] Rosbridge WebSocket server started on port 9090
[INFO] [WallTime: 1515408679.778950] Rosapi started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1515409221.835433] Client connected. 1 clients total.
the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
```

I also did an exemple flow to show that the websocket are connected to each other, and that I can publish a message, but no data is received by the subscriber:

[Node-red and console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAQxK.png)

In addition I provide you my node-red settings.js:

```js
/**
 * Copyright JS Foundation and other contributors, http://js.foundation
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 **/

// The `https` setting requires the `fs` module. Uncomment the following
// to make it available:
//var fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    // the tcp port that the Node-RED web server is listening on
    uiPort: process.env.PORT || 1880,

    // By default, the Node-RED UI accepts connections on all IPv4 interfaces.
    // The following property can be used to listen on a specific interface. For
    // example, the following would only allow connections from the local machine.
    //uiHost: "127.0.0.1",

    // Retry time in milliseconds for MQTT connections
    mqttReconnectTime: 15000,

    // Retry time in milliseconds for Serial port connections
    serialReconnectTime: 15000,

    // Retry time in milliseconds for TCP socket connections
    //socketReconnectTime: 10000,

    // Timeout in milliseconds for TCP server socket connections
    //  defaults to no timeout
    //socketTimeout: 120000,

    // Timeout in milliseconds for HTTP request connections
    //  defaults to 120 seconds
    //httpRequestTimeout: 120000,

    // The maximum length, in characters, of any message sent to the debug sidebar tab
    debugMaxLength: 1000,

    // To disable the option for using local files for storing keys and certificates in the TLS configuration
    //  node, set this to true
    //tlsConfigDisableLocalFiles: true,

    // Colourise the console output of the debug node
    //debugUseColors: true,

    // The file containing the flows. If not set, it defaults to flows_<hostname>.json
    //flowFile: 'flows.json',

    // To enabled pretty-printing of the flow within the flow file, set the following
    //  property to true:
    //flowFilePretty: true,

    // By default, credentials are encrypted in storage using a generated key. To
    // specify your own secret, set the following property.
    // If you want to disable encryption of credentials, set this property to false.
    // Note: once you set this property, do not change it - doing so will prevent
    // node-red from being able to decrypt your existing credentials and they will be
    // lost.
    //credentialSecret: "a-secret-key",

    // By default, all user data is stored in the Node-RED install directory. To
    // use a different location, the following property can be used
    //userDir: '/home/nol/.node-red/',

    // Node-RED scans the `nodes` directory in the install directory to find nodes.
    // The following property can be used to specify an additional directory to scan.
    //nodesDir: '/home/nol/.node-red/nodes',

    // By default, the Node-RED UI is available at http://localhost:1880/
    // The following property can be used to specifiy a different root path.
    // If set to false, this is disabled.
    //httpAdminRoot: '/admin',

    // Some nodes, such as HTTP In, can be used to listen for incoming http requests.
    // By default, these are served relative to '/'. The following property
    // can be used to specifiy a different root path. If set to false, this is
    // disabled.
    //httpNodeRoot: '/red-nodes',

    // The following property can be used in place of 'httpAdminRoot' and 'httpNodeRoot',
    // to apply the same root to both parts.
    //httpRoot: '/red',

    // When httpAdminRoot is used to move the UI to a different root path, the
    // following property can be used to identify a directory of static content
    // that should be served at http://localhost:1880/.
    //httpStatic: '/home/nol/node-red-static/',

    // The maximum size of HTTP request that will be accepted by the runtime api.
    // Default: 5mb
    //apiMaxLength: '5mb',

    // If you installed the optional node-red-dashboard you can set it's path
    // relative to httpRoot
    //ui: { path: "ui" },

    // Securing Node-RED
    // -----------------
    // To password protect the Node-RED editor and admin API, the following
    // property can be used. See http://nodered.org/docs/security.html for details.
    //adminAuth: {
    //    type: "credentials",
    //    users: [{
    //        username: "admin",
    //        password: "$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN.",
    //        permissions: "*"
    //    }]
    //},

    // To password protect the node-defined HTTP endpoints (httpNodeRoot), or
    // the static content (httpStatic), the following properties can be used.
    // The pass field is a bcrypt hash of the password.
    // See http://nodered.org/docs/security.html#generating-the-password-hash
    //httpNodeAuth: {user:"user",pass:"$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN."},
    //httpStaticAuth: {user:"user",pass:"$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN."},

    // The following property can be used to enable HTTPS
    // See http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener
    // for details on its contents.
    // See the comment at the top of this file on how to load the `fs` module used by
    // this setting.
    //
    //https: {
    //    key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
    //    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
    //},

    // The following property can be used to cause insecure HTTP connections to
    // be redirected to HTTPS.
    //requireHttps: true,

    // The following property can be used to disable the editor. The admin API
    // is not affected by this option. To disable both the editor and the admin
    // API, use either the httpRoot or httpAdminRoot properties
    //disableEditor: false,

    // The following property can be used to configure cross-origin resource sharing
    // in the HTTP nodes.
    // See https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors#configuration-options for
    // details on its contents. The following is a basic permissive set of options:
    //httpNodeCors: {
    //    origin: "*",
    //    methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
    //},

    // If you need to set an http proxy please set an environment variable
    // called http_proxy (or HTTP_PROXY) outside of Node-RED in the operating system.
    // For example - http_proxy=http://myproxy.com:8080
    // (Setting it here will have no effect)
    // You may also specify no_proxy (or NO_PROXY) to supply a comma separated
    // list of domains to not proxy, eg - no_proxy=.acme.co,.acme.co.uk

    // The following property can be used to add a custom middleware function
    // in front of all http in nodes. This allows custom authentication to be
    // applied to all http in nodes, or any other sort of common request processing.
    //httpNodeMiddleware: function(req,res,next) {
    //    // Handle/reject the request, or pass it on to the http in node by calling next();
    //    // Optionally skip our rawBodyParser by setting this to true;
    //    //req.skipRawBodyParser = true;
    //    next();
    //},

    // The following property can be used to verify websocket connection attempts.
    // This allows, for example, the HTTP request headers to be checked to ensure
    // they include valid authentication information.
    //webSocketNodeVerifyClient: function(info) {
    //    // 'info' has three properties:
    //    //   - origin : the value in the Origin header
    //    //   - req : the HTTP request
    //    //   - secure : true if req.connection.authorized or req.connection.encrypted is set
    //    //
    //    // The function should return true if the connection should be accepted, false otherwise.
    //    //
    //    // Alternatively, if this function is defined to accept a second argument, callback,
    //    // it can be used to verify the client asynchronously.
    //    // The callback takes three arguments:
    //    //   - result : boolean, whether to accept the connection or not
    //    //   - code : if result is false, the HTTP error status to return
    //    //   - reason: if result is false, the HTTP reason string to return
    //},

    // Anything in this hash is globally available to all functions.
    // It is accessed as context.global.
    // eg:
    //    functionGlobalContext: { os:require('os') }
    // can be accessed in a function block as:
    //    context.global.os

    functionGlobalContext: {
        // os:require('os'),
        // octalbonescript:require('octalbonescript'),
        // jfive:require("johnny-five"),
        // j5board:require("johnny-five").Board({repl:false})
    },

    // The following property can be used to order the categories in the editor
    // palette. If a node's category is not in the list, the category will get
    // added to the end of the palette.
    // If not set, the following default order is used:
    //paletteCategories: ['subflows', 'input', 'output', 'function', 'social', 'mobile', 'storage', 'analysis', 'advanced'],

    // Configure the logging output
    logging: {
        // Only console logging is currently supported
        console: {
            // Level of logging to be recorded. Options are:
            // fatal - only those errors which make the application unusable should be recorded
            // error - record errors which are deemed fatal for a particular request + fatal errors
            // warn - record problems which are non fatal + errors + fatal errors
            // info - record information about the general running of the application + warn + error + fatal errors
            // debug - record information which is more verbose than info + info + warn + error + fatal errors
            // trace - record very detailed logging + debug + info + warn + error + fatal errors
            // off - turn off all logging (doesn't affect metrics or audit)
            level: "info",
            // Whether or not to include metric events in the log output
            metrics: false,
            // Whether or not to include audit events in the log output
            audit: false
        }
    }
}
```

and my flow.json:

```
[{"id":"9ae04cfc.d14608","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1"},{"id":"96795014.80fc6","type":"ros-server","z":"","url":"ws://10.68.0.1:9090"},{"id":"f116cefa.8daf58","type":"ros-subscribe","z":"9ae04cfc.d14608","server":"96795014.80fc6","topicname":"/tf","x":150,"y":100,"wires":[["8ed9ceb9.0ab2a8"]]},{"id":"8ed9ceb9.0ab2a8","type":"debug","z":"9ae04cfc.d14608","name":"","active":true,"console":"true","complete":"payload","x":460,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"a62956a6.4035a8","type":"ros-publish","z":"9ae04cfc.d14608","server":"96795014.80fc6","topicname":"/tf","msgtype":"std_msgs/String","x":430,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"d36faeb2.3b9fa8","type":"inject","z":"9ae04cfc.d14608","name":"Fake Data","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":143.5,"y":219,"wires":[["a62956a6.4035a8"]]}]
```

Also, when I try to go to the settings or node palette, node-red says me that it can't connect and retrieve catalog, maybe I'm simply having connection issue between node-red and my PC network ?

At the same time, I'm having issues with my https connection to node-red. I tried to uncomment all the https part in node-red settings.js but it stills only allow connection on http protocol.

Comment: Maybe we need some other information to help you do you have any snippet or other data avaliable ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, it was coming from the Rosbridge_server configuration.

I was working with a custom version of the Rosbridge_suite, but wasn't aware that it was a custom one, with a 'node type' blocking parameters.

Starting another rosbridge_server from the latest git rosbridge_suite package into a separate workspace solved my troubles.

Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: What did you have to launch to get this to work? I'm calling roscore then roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch with no luck.